What Databases Are Used by FMOD and Wwise for 3D Audio?
I'm conducting research comparing 3D audio capabilities between FMOD and Wwise, specifically focusing on sound localization and spatialization accuracy. However, I couldn't find any information in the documentation or online resources regarding the databases or internal datasets used by these engines to handle 3D audio data (e.g., for HRTF or environmental modeling).
Does anyone have insights into the HRTF databases or data models FMOD and Wwise rely on for 3D audio processing?
I’ve been searching through the official documentation, forums, GitHub repositories, and various Google searches, but I haven’t been able to find any information

What information did you find already? Also I don't think this is a "find-me-a-manual" website. Did you read the FMOD maunal and wwise documentation. What was missing in there that you don't understand? Otherwise, raising an issue there will maybe get you responses earlier.

I can only speak for FMOD, but the only HRTF processing we do is via the Resonance Audio spatializer plugin. Resonance uses the SADIE database referenced here. All other spatialization is performed using VBAP (vector based amplitude panning).
